# How to use google voice search api with C#?

Tags: c#, voice-recognition

I'm trying to create a application for blind persons using C#. So I'm trying to use microsoft speech sdk for voice recognition. But unfortunately it does not work for me. I'm not native English speaker (I'm in Sri Lanka). So I'm trying to use Google voice Search api. Please help...

Comment: Did you try anything so far?

Comment: I found sample project in [http://habrahabr.ru/post/117234/](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117234/) . But it in russian.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for some thing like this `[google lib][1]`

You can also use windows speech library , i have already done a voice activated project before 2 year.